# AmazonMQ and ActiveMQ - sending messages greater than or equal to 100 MB limitation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

We use Amazon MQ, ActiveMQ, and OpenWire for our event-driven messaging system.

The Max frame size that can be received is 104,857,600 (100 MB). When looking through the broker logs within AWS after sending a message (using postman) that equated to 103 MB, it is clearly stated that 100 MB is the limit.

When reaching out to AWS Support, they mentioned that the AmazonMQ service team have implemented these restrictions for security reasons and will get back to me if/how I can increase this limitation.

I am assuming that if they do have a solution to increase it, it will not be by much. Which leads me to this question – does anyone know of any ways around this wall? Are you able to edit the Amazon MQ configuration xml file to support this max frame size increase?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Your best option would be to chunk the message into smaller payloads and then reassemble them on the other end. Another approach is to upload the files to S3 and then either use an S3 trigger to drop a message on the queue or to have the client drop the message onto the queue.

Comment: You might consider moving to ActiveMQ Artemis as it supports [arbitrarily large messages](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html).